# Changing location of files stored using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to upload images. In uploaders/image_uploader.rb, I have

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
   '/public/uploads/images'
 end
end
```

I would like to move the uploads directory to:

```
/shared/uploads/images
```

I obviously need to modify uploaders/image_uploader.rb to reflect the new path. In addition, I need to move the already uploaded images from:

```
/public/uploads/images
```

to:

```
/shared/uploads/images
```

My assumption is that these are the only changes I need to make, as in I don't have to make any changes to the DB or anything else. Is this correct?

Comment: you can also create a sym link.

Comment: @archit_gupta: this does not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to change the side of the DB.

To be safe, you just have to see how its stored your images.
;)